# How do I implement Google Apps Script best practices using stylesheet.html?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm studying "[HTML Service: Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)"

and I am wanting to bring in variables into my styles.  I know how to bring them in if I put my styles in the page.html but no luck when trying to use the "HTML Service: Best Practices" example put out by Google.

my broken page.html looks like

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>

<br />
<div id="title"><?= data.myTitle ?></div>
<div id="thanksMessage">
<p><?= data.myText ?></p>
</div>
<p>More text</p>
```

my broken Stylesheet.html looks like

```
<style>
<? var data = Code.gs.getData(); ?>
@tcolor: #4D926F;
@tcolor2: <?= data.myTitleColorValue ?>;

p {
  color: #da0202;
}

#thanksMessage {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 50%;
  color: #da0202;  
}

#title {
  font-size: 3.3em;
  line-height: 50%;
  color: <?= data.myTitleColorValue ?>;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

My working Code.gs looks like

```
  function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}

    function getData() {
     var myValues = {}; 
     myValues["myTitleColorValue"] = "#da0202"  
     myValues["myTitle"] = "Hello Friends"  
     myValues["myText"] = "Thank-you for your help!"  
     return myValues;
    };
```

So I made it work by bringing the 'styles' into the page.html like this

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<style>
p {
  color: #da0202;
}

#thanksMessage {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 50%;
  color: #da0202;  
}

#title {
  font-size: 3.3em;
  line-height: 50%;
  c/olor: #da0202;
  c/olor: @tcolor;
  color: <?= data.myTitleColorValue ?>;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
<br />
<div id="title"><?= data.myTitle ?></div>
<div id="thanksMessage">
<p><?= data.myText ?></p>
</div>
<p>More text</p>
```

I am hoping someone can help me see my errors.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `include()` function currently looks like this:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}
```

I use this:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
};
```

I'd remove the sandbox mode method, and see if that works.  Actually, the sandbox method should be in your `doGet()` function.

I just noticed that your Stylesheet.html file has scriptlets in it.  I'd put those in your main page.html file.

Comment: Sandy, I put the sandbox in the 'doget' cleaning that up and yes the Stylesheet.html has scriptlets in it.  That is the part that I am having issues with.  So I think you are saying if your Stylesheet.html  needs scriptlets then the styles need to be in the page.html and that I will not be able to make them work in the Stylesheet.html page... correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if the scriptlets work in pages other than the file being served in the `doGet()` function.  But, everything ends up in one place anyway.  The only reason to break things up into multiple files, is to be able to make sense of your code and find stuff faster.  If it wasn't for that, you'd just put everything in the same file anyway.  It all ends up in one big mass of code in the end.  So, if you put scriptlets in the main page.html file, that info is available to everything else.  Anything returned in a scriptlet is still available to your Stylesheet.html file.